# Repository Pattern in Android. Is there any way better than this?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, repository-pattern

I have an app based on MVVM architecture.
I have two modules that repository and datasource. 
And using coroutines. I came across some projects on Github they applied different ways.

My implementation like this;

```
You can think naming as login, profile etc. instead of X letter
```

datasource interface

```
interface IXDatasource{
   suspend fun fetchData(): LiveData<XResponse>
}
```

datasource implementation

```
class XDatasourceImp  @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) : IXDatasource{
   suspend fun fetchData(): LiveData<XResponse> {
       // getting data
       return xResponse
   }
}
```

repository interface

```
 interface XRepository {
    suspend fun getXData(): LiveData<XResponse>
 }
```

repository implementation

```
class XRepositoryImp @Inject constructor(private val iDatasource: IXDatasource): XRepository {
    override suspend fun getXData(): LiveData<XResponse> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            iDatasource.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

I called this in my ViewModel

```
class XViewModel @Inject constructor(xRepository: XRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
    val xModel by lazyDeferred {
        xRepository.getXData()
    }
}
```

And I use in my activity/fragment

```
private fun init() = launch {
    val xModel = viewModel.xModel.await()
    xModel.observe(this@MyActivity, Observer {
        if (it == null) {
            return@Observer
        }
        // filling views or doing sth
   })
}
```

It works but I wonder all of them is required or not? I can apply the room database to my datasource. Is there any way better than this? I know it can change by the case of the app. I try to find the best way. I will be happy if you suggest anything or share anything about repository pattern implementation.

Comment: If you want to remove `DataSource` then consider using this class (NetworkBoundResource) directly https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum